# cassandra - only superuser is allowed to perform CREATE USER queries

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm logging in with on Ubuntu 14.10 on Cassandra 2.0.8 with Java 1.7.0_60-b19

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

I'm running:

```
CREATE USER a WITH PASSWORD 'a' NOSUPERUSER;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Bad Request: Only superusers are allowed to perform CREATE USER queries
```

The problem with reasoning - I am logged in as the superuser.

My question is: **If I'm logged into cqlsh as the Cassandra user, why am I told that I'm not the superuser?**

Comment: Before setting up the authenticator in cassandra.yaml, it assumes that you are an anonymous user. Hence, you don't have permission to create a superuser.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to enable PasswordAuthenticator in cassandra.yaml file.
To enable PasswordAuthenticator you need to change authenticator property in cassandra.yaml

Change

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
```

to

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

After that login with following command and then you will be able to add new user

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Comment: just in case someone is looking to grant permissions as well, you would need to add below to cassandra.yaml.  authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer

Answer (score 3):

1 Find and open 'cassandra.yaml' file on your computer.

2 Find and delete 'authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator' in the file.

3 Replace it with 'authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator'

4 Also, add this line : 'authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer '

Restart Cassandra.
If you use brew, you can restart using

> brew services restart cassandra

then log in to cql shell again:

> cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra localhost;

create a new super user

> CREATE ROLE  WITH SUPERUSER = TRUE AND LOGIN = TRUE AND PASSWORD = '';

exit out of cassandra

> exit

log in using the new super user login

> cql -u

Then you enter your password and you're in!

https://gist.github.com/GHesericsu/83aca87b60c853945e242b3b9a6ceef0/edit